# Firebase DataBase snapshot.getValue(.class) return null

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I connected Firebase DataBase to my app via Firebase tool, and it has no problem writing data to database. However, I am facing a problem of not being able to read it.

ArrayList events is used to fill ListView, but hen using getValue(Event.class),event is null.

```
   myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Event event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                    events.add(event);
                }
            }
```

Event class

```
package com.example.volunteer.classes;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Event implements Serializable {
    protected String title;
    protected String location;
    protected String desc;
    private String host_username;
    protected String reqs;
    protected String event_img;
    protected long date;
    private String key;
    public Event(){};

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Event(String title, String location, String desc, String host_username, String reqs, long date){
        this.title = title;
        this.location = location;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.host_username = host_username;
        this.reqs = reqs;
        this.date = date;
    }

    }
}
```

It was supposed to fill ArrayList events with objects from Firebase, however debugger shows that it is empty.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, please also show us how `myRef` is defined.